# c# How does Process.Start() method automatically know where files are located?

Tags: c#, directory, process.start

If I feed `Process.Start();` the parameters `"Firefox"`, `Notepad` or `"cmd"` it runs those programs like their location is built in, but with other programs I have to specify the program's directory for it to work.

How does it automatically know where some programs located, and why only those programs and not others?

My code:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Testing
{
 public class MainClass
 {
   static void Main()
   {
      Process.Start("Firefox");    // Works
      Process.Start("Notepad");    // Works 
      Process.Start(@"C:\Users\user\Desktop\Steam");   // Works too
      Process.Start("Steam");      // This line gives me "The System cannot find the file specified"(run-time error)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Same place than the 'Run' thingy (Windows + R), which is probably the PATH variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it depends on *Environment variables* in Windows.
or type **PATH** in cmd and observe paths, where *.exe files can be found automatically.

Comment: I've done just that, yet none of those paths contain Firefox, Notepad, or CMD

Comment: @JackBarn. It is impossible - **PATH** always contains by default *Program Files* and *Program Files (x86)* folders, where Notepad and Firefox are installed by default

Comment: After looking around on the internet, it seems your right